# Application owner issue

Tags: android

I want to publish my application to android market and I have a question to ask. I am just wondering where I can define owner names of the application. I want the owner name to be seen in users willing to download my application. Is it possible to define the owner name when I sign my application? If not can I define it when I publish my application to android market?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it at the time you publish it to the market. You also can include your name/company in the cert with which you sign your application - but nobody will see ( from the  user stand point ).
Sign to the market you see the form where you specify all those things.